# Office Automation OpenCurrentDatabase method visible Window

Tags: .net, ms-access, automation, office-interop

I've inherited some vb.net code that does the following (I've cut out the bits that are irrelevant):

```
    Dim oAccess As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application
    oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(dbfile, True)

    Dim MyXmlFiles() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(tempStr, fileprefix & "*.xml")
        For Each xmlfile In MyXmlFiles
            oAccess.ImportXML(xmlfile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcImportXMLOption.acAppendData)
        Next
```

It's running on 3 machines. On one you can see it opening Access and doing all the work but on the other two, they are not visible and are immensely faster.

I appreciate it's running under Office Automation and should therefore quite probably be visible on all of them, but something is making two of them not visible and I'd like to do that without changing any code.

Any idea?
thanks.

Comment: Actually, I find it odd that one is visible. Usually requires code to set object visible.

Comment: Do all have the same version of Microsoft Access installed? Or maybe not all are the full version of Access, but a just the runtime version?